# How to iterate PyQt4 list with images

Tags: python, pyqt

I have created an global list named

```
MyGlobals.stepsOutput = []
```

And I have multiple files across my project where in each file I am appending the list with Image. Images are getting stored correctly, for printing, these are the instructions i am using

```
for i in range (0,len(MyGlobals.stepsOutput)):
        print MyGlobals.stepsOutput[i]
```

but when i try to print the list, i am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\Project\nano.py", line 477, in exeScript
 for i in range (0,len(MyGlobals.stepsOutput)):
TypeError: object of type 'QImage' has no len()
```

even i tried the following lines of code

```
for i in enumerate(MyGlobals.stepsOutput):
        print MyGlobals.stepsOutput
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Project\nano.py", line 477, in exeScript
for i in enumerate(MyGlobals.stepsOutput):
TypeError: 'QImage' object is not iterable
```

So how do i need to iterate the list which contains images?

Comment: You could add the code of how you add QImage to MyGlobals.stepsOutput.

Comment: MyGlobals.stepsOutput.append(MyGlobals.image) is the line where image is appended to the list, if I print individually it prints perfectly such as <PyQt4.QtGui.QImage object at 0x04138070>

Comment: `from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

l = []
for i in range(10):
    l.append(QImage())

print(l)

for i in enumerate(l):
    print(i)

sys.exit(app.exec_())` . I did a test and I had no problems

Comment: thanks a lot all images are getting printed perfectly

Comment: What did you modify?